# Python: best way to serve multiple users?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a (game) server that I am writing in python (3.1), and have a few questions on that.

The client program uses the socket module to connect to the server.

Multiple people may be connecting at any time, and I need a way to handle that. Would the best way be to employ the multi/sub processing module, and start a new process for each user who logs in, or is there a better way ?

Files will be used to store data. Do I need a lot of complex Queuing to handle file I/O ?

Is there an easy way to serve an entire file to the client, e.g. for an automated update ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you handling connections? Something you've rolled yourself, or Twisted, or a web framework like Django, or something else again? If using something like Twisted or Django the problem is reduced very significantly.

Comment: The client program uses the socket module to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/core/howto/servers.html).